# How to store/represent dynamic "sub-groups" created with user-provided filters on a parent `contacts` table?

Tags: sql, mysql, ecto

We have a `contacts` table with the following structure:

| id | name | email | status | last_appointment_at | campaign_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith | jsmith@example.com | HOT | 2023-01-01 | 1 | ... |
| 2 | Jane Doe | jdoe@example.com | COLD | NULL | 1 | ... |
| 3 | Alex Wu | a_wu@example.com | WARM | 2023-05-11 | 2 | ... |
| 4 | Allie May | may@example.com | HOT | 2023-03-24 | 1 | ... |

We want to support user-created "groups" for targeted marketing and improved analytics. These contact groups would essentially be saved filters:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts
WHERE last_appointment_at > '2023-02-01' AND status IN ('HOT', 'WARM');
```

What is the best way to represent/cache subgroups created with filters on the parent `contacts` table? Ideally the relationship would be dynamic, so if a contact's `status` is changed, they are removed or added to a group.

Our initial thinking was a `contacts_groups` join table that is updated asynchronously at regular intervals:

| contact_id | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 10 | 1 |
| 99 | 3 |
| 99 | 2 |

The `contacts_groups` table would just serve as a cache that is cleared and updated every hour or so. Is there a better way to achieve this while maintaining a real relationship between contacts and the groups they fall under?

Comment: yes such a bridge table resoresents a n:m relation ship and can be used, to keep track of groups

Comment: When you describe these as "saved filters" do you mean that they are dynamic (i.e. they will be applied whenever the filter is used - so the records returned can change) or are they static (the filter is applied at a point in time and all the records returned by that filter are then included regardless of any subsequent changes to the data)?

Comment: @NickW ideally they would be dynamic and the records returned would change. It doesn't have to be immediate, but periodically the groups should be updated.

Comment: Why not just create views, then?

Comment: @NickW, I thought about views but I'm worried about it becoming difficult to create/manage a significant number of user-defined views, especially in our Elixir based application and the Ecto MySQL adapter.

Comment: While if there are a large number of views it may be difficult to manage, I'm not sure why you think managing the same number of "dynamic filters" would be less difficult - given that views are a standard DB construct that everyone understands and you're looking at building some custom construct?

Comment: Are the filters arbitrary, or is there some (relatively limited) number of constraint operations you can apply? Min/max dates, allowed statuses, anything else? The fewer of these operations you support, the easier it is to construct a constraint table.

Comment: @Reinderien, the filters are limited to about 10 fields on the contacts table, and the fields are an even mix of integer, text, and date types. We'll support a limited number of comparison operators (equal, not equal, gt, lt, ...), `IN` for arrays, and `contains` for strings.

Comment: Our main challenge is finding a solution meeting these three criteria:
1. Can be created by end-users easily.
2. Contacts belonging to different groups are updated dynamically (or at scheduled intervals)
3. Contacts and the groups they belong to have some DB relationship.